# Python strip document of image tags

Tags: python, input, beautifulsoup, output, edit

I would like to write a script which will remove all images from a simple html file in Python, and save the file in place.

Here is my attempt :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = ""

            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
                s += unicode(c)

            tag.replaceWith(s)

    return soup

data ="C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Documents\\webpage 1.htm"
with open(data) as orig_f:
        html = BeautifulSoup(orig_f.read())
        invalid_tags = ['img']
        print orig_f
        print strip_tags(orig_f, invalid_tags)
```

There are two things I am struggling with, first of all the code runs with no bugs, but the last line, the print, prints nothing, and the line before that prints a memory address. I've tried searching for my issue/reading the documents to understand what I am doing incorrectly here, but am struggling.

How can I make this code remove all image tags from my HTML file, and what is the best practice for saving it in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"orig_f" is a file object. If you want to print the content one way would be to do orig_f.read() or loop over f and print each line. I think thats why the strip_tags functions returns None. I have not used BeautifulSoap so can't say what it will return.

For the inplace saving, I have always made a copy of the file in a temp location and open the temp file for reading before overwriting the current file. This is cause files may be to huge to be stored in the memory, I deal with large ascii files which may crash if all the content are loaded in one go.